# how can I setup Powerline in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, terminal, powerline

when I try to install powerline in my PowerShell the following error will appear

[the error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuBHX.png)

Comment: Try run as admin

Comment: Your actual user name is `$PESHA$`?

Comment: Yes it is my actual user name.